# Creating a vector of Annual Discount Rates for the Next N Years

Tags: r

I am new to R (coming from Python).  I am attempting to create a for loop (or perhaps something more efficient?) which creates a vector of annual discount rates over the next N years.   In a sense turning this code:

```
r <- 0.01
ADR <- c((1 / (1 + r)) ** (1),
        (1 / (1 + r)) ** (2),
        (1 / (1 + r)) ** (3))
```

Into something more scalable, as I would in Python, like:

```
r = 0.01
ADR = [(1/(1+r)) ** i for i in range(1,3)] # or indeed (1,N) so I could do multiple years
```

Any help making this as neat and scalable as possible would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this might help

```
r <- 0.01
ADR <- 1/(1+r)**(1:3)
```

which gives

```
> ADR
[1] 0.9900990 0.9802960 0.9705901
```

Comment: @MrFlick Good comments